# Magento Custom Image Attribute from Related Products

Tags: image, magento

So from the product view i am getting related products to display. For reasons i wont get into  i need to display the image of the related product but it has to be a custom image attribute. So i have created a custom image attribute called colour_swatch and i need to access it and display it on screen. I have done some reading on the issue and have not managed to find a solution to fit my needs.

So here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <div class="eachProductRelated">
        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'colour_swatch') ?>"
                 width="20px" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>"/>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

If we replace colour_swatch with small image that of course will work. I have read that you can't access a custom image attribute if you aren't calling it directly from the product view. And a lot of the solutions i have seen seem to be massively overkill, Surely there is a simpler solution???

Might be worth telling you that i get the following error message:

> a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Image file was not found.";i:1;s:4015:"#0
>   /Users/Frank/Sites/bosideng/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile(NULL)

Is it possible that i have to do some kind of if no_selected check ?

Comment: Did you do a reindex of the product flat table?

Comment: Yes i did do a full reindex. caches cleared etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out this issue and pardon my French but it was a ridiculous and a stupid oversight by Magento.

When setting up your new custom image attribute you must set 'Use In Product Listing' to **yes** in the drop down before you select the attribute type 'Media Image' because guess what!? When you select Media Image, Magento hides that option.

Credit to this guy whose post i found after ages of searching: http://thedistance.co.uk/journal/2011-10/missing-magento-media-images

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you add new image url in custom image attribute then call may be help you

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product)->getData('colour_swatch'); ?>"
```

Comment: unfortunatly that just gives me <img src="" width="20px" alt="Sports Hooded Down Jacket With Detachable Hood">

Answer (score 0):

For those of you creating custom image type using installer, add the following to make image visible on both listing and view pages:

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'colour_swatch', array(
    'group'             => 'Images',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'frontend'          => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
    'label'             => 'Color Swatch',
    'input'             => 'media_image',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product is set to Yes, then you can add the specific attributes to the collection

Like

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('attributes_name');
```

This is working perfect for me